# Get bigrams and trigrams in word2vec Gensim

Tags: python, tokenize, word2vec, gensim, n-gram

I am currently using uni-grams in my word2vec model as follows.

```
def review_to_sentences( review, tokenizer, remove_stopwords=False ):
    #Returns a list of sentences, where each sentence is a list of words
    #
    #NLTK tokenizer to split the paragraph into sentences
    raw_sentences = tokenizer.tokenize(review.strip())

    sentences = []
    for raw_sentence in raw_sentences:
        # If a sentence is empty, skip it
        if len(raw_sentence) > 0:
            # Otherwise, call review_to_wordlist to get a list of words
            sentences.append( review_to_wordlist( raw_sentence, \
              remove_stopwords ))
    #
    # Return the list of sentences (each sentence is a list of words,
    # so this returns a list of lists
    return sentences
```

However, then I will miss important bigrams and trigrams in my dataset.

```
E.g.,
"team work" -> I am currently getting it as "team", "work"
"New York" -> I am currently getting it as "New", "York"
```

Hence, I want to capture the important bigrams, trigrams etc. in my dataset and input into my word2vec model.

I am new to wordvec and struggling how to do it. Please help me.

Comment: Provide some code and a better example. The example you're showing doesnt reflect the data you provided in the first line

Comment: Done! Updated the question. Please help me to solve this issue.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

First of all you should use gensim's class [Phrases](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/phrases.html) in order to get bigrams, which works as pointed in the doc

```
>>> bigram = Phraser(phrases)
>>> sent = [u'the', u'mayor', u'of', u'new', u'york', u'was', u'there']
>>> print(bigram[sent])
[u'the', u'mayor', u'of', u'new_york', u'was', u'there']
```

To get trigrams and so on, you should use the bigram model that you already have and apply Phrases to it again, and so on. 
Example:

```
trigram_model = Phrases(bigram_sentences)
```

Also there is a good notebook and video that explains how to use that .... [the notebook](https://github.com/skipgram/modern-nlp-in-python/blob/master/executable/Modern_NLP_in_Python.ipynb), [the video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6zm9NC9uRkk&list=PLw5BhoADa9fUtHRGND_rrdeZlv1XFM8In&index=14&t=3339s)

The most important part of it is how to use it in real life sentences which is as follows:

```
// to create the bigrams
bigram_model = Phrases(unigram_sentences)

// apply the trained model to a sentence
 for unigram_sentence in unigram_sentences:                
            bigram_sentence = u' '.join(bigram_model[unigram_sentence])

// get a trigram model out of the bigram
trigram_model = Phrases(bigram_sentences)
```

Hope this helps you, but next time give us more information on what you are using and etc.

P.S: Now that you edited it, you are not doing anything in order to get bigrams just splitting it, you have to use Phrases in order to get words like New York as bigrams.

Comment: Thank you for your valuable answer. But when I use bigram = Phraser(phrases). it says undefined name Phraser and phrases. Do I need to import them?

Comment: @Volka Yes you need to import them, it is in the models of gensim, I know gensim docs are confusing sometimes

Comment: @nitheism Please let me know if you know an answer for this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46137572/error-in-extracting-phrases-using-gensim

Comment: Generally it is good to remove stop words and stem after you created your n-gram dictionary.

Answer (score 12):

```
from gensim.models import Phrases

from gensim.models.phrases import Phraser

documents = [
  "the mayor of new york was there", 
  "machine learning can be useful sometimes",
  "new york mayor was present"
  ]

sentence_stream = [doc.split(" ") for doc in documents]
print(sentence_stream)

bigram = Phrases(sentence_stream, min_count=1, threshold=2, delimiter=b' ')

bigram_phraser = Phraser(bigram)


print(bigram_phraser)

for sent in sentence_stream:
    tokens_ = bigram_phraser[sent]

    print(tokens_)
```

Comment: @user8566323     you need to import below                                            
from gensim.models import Phrases
                                                                                                                                                                            from gensim.models.phrases import Phraser

Comment: It would be nice to know the output of Phrases and Phraser and what bigram and bigram_phraser looks like. What about Word2Vec with sg=1, for skip gram=1 with negative sampling and window

Comment: @tgrandje when I run your code above, it works till print(sentence_stream) but when I get to 

bigram = Phrases(sentence_stream, min_count=1, threshold=2, delimiter=b' ')

I get following error:

TypeError: sequence item 0: expected a bytes-like object, str found

Comment: @seakyourpeak : that's not my code (I just fixed a typo), but I seem to remember you can replace the b' ' délimiter by a simple ' '. I'm not sure if this code could date to python 2.x so I didn't take the liberty to change that...

Comment: I replaced the delimiter with ___ and it worked.  Basically, the delimiter open uses the delimiter provided to connect the words to form phrases (e.g. bigram or trigram)

Answer (score 3):

Phrases and Phraser are those you should looking for

```
bigram = gensim.models.Phrases(data_words, min_count=1, threshold=10) # higher threshold fewer phrases.
trigram = gensim.models.Phrases(bigram[data_words], threshold=100)
```

Once you are enough done with adding vocabs then use Phraser for faster access and efficient memory usage. Not mandatory but useful.

```
bigram_mod = gensim.models.phrases.Phraser(bigram)
trigram_mod = gensim.models.phrases.Phraser(trigram)
```

Thanks,

Comment: How to use it for train and test data? I want to use train data to learn phrases and then transform it to test. How can I do that?